# NHibernate QueryOver Alias Issue

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I'm using the latest version of NHibernate (3.3.1.4000) from NuGet in .Net 4 targeted project in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

When I attempt to follow examples I've seen for defining aliases, I get an exception when setting them up using lambdas (see screenshot).

[image: Shows error 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string'...]

As you can see I'm getting the error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`.

I have references to the LINQ namespaces in the top of my code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use a variable like `role` in an expression, you have to define it first, like so...

```
Role roleAlias = null; // <-- these two lines are missing from your code.
Person personAlias = null; 

var x = session.QueryOver<Role>(() => roleAlias)
    .JoinAlias(r => r.People, () => personAlias)
    // ...
```

`ISession.QueryOver<T>(...)` has four overloads:

- `.QueryOver<T>()`
- `.QueryOver<T>(Expression<Func<T>> alias)`
- `.QueryOver<T>(string entityName)`
- `.QueryOver<T>(string entityName, Expression<Func<T>> alias)`

Apparently because it can't figure out what `role` is, it's assuming you're trying to use the `.QueryOver<T>(string entityName)` overload, hence the "Cannot convert ... to type 'string'" error message.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be the correct answer. I thought there was something else going on. Didn't realize I needed to create variables to use them as aliases. But after reading your answer I went back to the docs, and sure enough it's right there in 16.5. Aliases (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-aliases).